# Menu items do not “open” when mouse hover over them?

Tags: menus, dropdown

My site is very old now and has worked fine up until the most recent WP update.

My menu items do not “open” when mouse over them? I can see that the theme uses Superfish but can't find anything that will fix my issue.

If anybody could help I'd be eternally grateful, the site is https://www.robsonwalsh.com/

Kind regards
Shaun

Comment: WordPress 5.6 shipped with a new/updated version of jQuery and I believe Superfish uses jQuery - so if your site is old, then it stands to reason that your Superfish script is old and relying on a now deprecated version of jQuery.  Try this out, but keep in mind that it's a temporary fix until you can get everything updated: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/

Comment: I did in fact try that before my post, unfortunately, it did not work. I did, however, find an edited version of the JS that seemed to work fine. Many thanks for your input. Stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

You Can Add This css In style.css or Wordpress Admin panel Option : Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS  and  Save css

```
#nav .menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: unset !important;
}
```

[image]